# pandas computation in each group

Tags: python, pandas

I do have a grouped data frame. Here is one group as an example:

```
name    pH   salt  id   
sample  7.5  50    1        0.48705
                   2        0.42875
                   3        0.38885
                   4        0.34615
                   5        0.35060
                   6        0.29280
                   7        0.28210
                   8        0.24535
                   stock    0.66090
```

for every group, there is a stock solution which defines my initial mass. I would like to iterate over all groups and subtract the initial mass from each item. I would like to do that without explicitly writing something like `df_grouped['sample'][7.5][50]`. If possible, I would like to avoid any nested loops.

Any suggestions?

I can only think of a solution like:

```
for na, gr in df_label_gr:
    if 'stock' in na:
        print(na)
```

This gives me:

```
('sample', 7.5, 50.0, 'stock')
('sample', 7.5, 150.0, 'stock')
('sample', 8.5, 50.0, 'stock')
('sample', 8.5, 150.0, 'stock')
```

So I could somehow use the first three entries to index my groups and do some calculations.

EDIT:

in order to not mess the discussion up, i ask the same question with a small modification again here:

The difference is that here I would like to subtract not the same value from each group but do it group specific,

```
name    pH   salt  id   
sample  7.5  50    1        0.48705
                   2        0.42875
                   3        0.38885
                   4        0.34615
                   5        0.35060
                   6        0.29280
                   7        0.28210
                   8        0.24535
                   stock    0.66090
sample  8.5  50    1        0.48705
                   2        0.42875
                   3        0.38885
                   4        0.34615
                   5        0.35060
                   6        0.29280
                   7        0.28210
                   8        0.24535
                   stock    0.1
```

I tried the following:

```
df = a2_01.df.reset_index()
df.groupby(by = ['name','pH','salt','id']).aggregate(np.sum).apply(lambda x: x - x[x.index.get_level_values('id') == 'stock'].values[0])
```

the problem is, that `x[x.index.get_level_values('id') == 'stock'].values` gives me an array of all values and not the value of the actual group. So i could substract e.g the sample with id == stock from the first group ( `values[0]`), from all values in the dataframe.

How could I subtract the value of the stocks only from the samples in the same group?

Comment: Can you show `df_grouped.info()`?

Comment: No, it does not work. The series i showed has no such attribute. And apllying info() to the grouped dataframe itself gives me following message:
AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'info' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method

Comment: What i showed here is just one group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think @filmor answered your question. Probably you misunderstood it.

I made up a dataframe by repeating the data you gave and modified indices.

```
In [117]: df
Out[117]: 
                          mass
name   pH  salt id            
sample 7.5 50   1      0.48705
                2      0.42875
                3      0.38885
                4      0.34615
                5      0.35060
                6      0.29280
                7      0.28210
                8      0.24535
                stock  0.66090
           150  1      0.48705
                2      0.42875
                3      0.38885
                4      0.34615
                5      0.35060
                6      0.29280
                7      0.28210
                8      0.24535
                stock  0.66090
       8.5 50   1      0.48705
                2      0.42875
                3      0.38885
                4      0.34615
                5      0.35060
                6      0.29280
                7      0.28210
                8      0.24535
                stock  0.66090
           150  1      0.48705
                2      0.42875
                3      0.38885
                4      0.34615
                5      0.35060
                6      0.29280
                7      0.28210
                8      0.24535
                stock  0.66090

[36 rows x 1 columns]
```

If you are sure `stock` is always last (after sorting if necessary) in each group, you can do the following. Otherwise, `df.groupby(level= [0,1,2]).apply(lambda g: g - g[g.index.get_level_values('id')=='stock'].values[0])` should work.

```
In [118]: df.groupby(level= [0,1,2]).apply(lambda g: g - g.iloc[-1,0])
Out[118]: 
                          mass
name   pH  salt id            
sample 7.5 50   1     -0.17385
                2     -0.23215
                3     -0.27205
                4     -0.31475
                5     -0.31030
                6     -0.36810
                7     -0.37880
                8     -0.41555
                stock  0.00000
           150  1     -0.17385
                2     -0.23215
                3     -0.27205
                4     -0.31475
                5     -0.31030
                6     -0.36810
                7     -0.37880
                8     -0.41555
                stock  0.00000
       8.5 50   1     -0.17385
                2     -0.23215
                3     -0.27205
                4     -0.31475
                5     -0.31030
                6     -0.36810
                7     -0.37880
                8     -0.41555
                stock  0.00000
           150  1     -0.17385
                2     -0.23215
                3     -0.27205
                4     -0.31475
                5     -0.31030
                6     -0.36810
                7     -0.37880
                8     -0.41555
                stock  0.00000

[36 rows x 1 columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `groupby` for this, in particular `df_grouped.groupby(level=[0, 1, 2]).apply(fancy_func)` in your case, where `fancy_func` takes a sub-dataframe and returns a value.

The result will then be a series of values, indexed by the same levels.

Comment: But i cannot group twice ? My grouped object does not have a grouped method.

Comment: So `df_grouped` is already a groupby object? That would have been valuable information in the question, don't you think? :)

Comment: Well, i wrote it in the first line of my question.

Comment: But i realize more and more often that communication is a difficult task. Not to say the most difficult thing i ever tried to deal with.

Comment: No worries, the given solution still applies, you just have to call it inside of an apply of your groupby: `df.groupby(bla).apply(lambda df_grouped: df_grouped.groupby(level=[0,1,2]).apply(fancy_func))`

Comment: What i do not understand is the level. I can do that only with a series but not with a dataframe. With a dataframe i have to say by =

Comment: The `level` argument lets you group by a level of a multiindex and works for both `Series` and `Index` objects.

Comment: in my case i get an error: `unorderable types: list() > int()` when i use `level` on my dataframe. I an only group by the column names (using `by = [name','pH','salt','id']`